group data by beginning letter
I would like to group strings by starting letter. I try below code:
import  itertools
import functools
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(['abc', 'abcd','bcd','bcdef', 'ghk', 'ghkabc', 'abc', 'ghk'])

obj = itertools.groupby(data, key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a,b: a[0] != b[0]))
for k,g in obj:
    print(k, list(g))

Output:
<functools.KeyWrapper object at 0x7774a81389a0> ['bcd', 'bcdef']
<functools.KeyWrapper object at 0x7774a8138970> ['ghk', 'ghkabc']
<functools.KeyWrapper object at 0x7774a81389d0> ['abc']
<functools.KeyWrapper object at 0x7774a8138880> ['ghk']

Some things not as expected:

The k print out is a object, how to print it as a readable value?
The group two and four should be combined to one group.


Why would groups 2 and three be combined to one group? Do you want only the starting letter or the lowest common denominator?

fixed a typo, should group two and four. I mean use first later as group condition.

ok, I am adding an answer accordingly

You neglected to sort before invoking.groupby().
Pass in “sorted(data)”.

I don’t understand why you’re using that legacy cmp_to_key() function.
A def or lambda that simply returns the initial character would suffice.
And then you could just trivially display each K value that comes back.

Good catch. how should I print the key?

data.groupby(data.apply(lambda x: x[0])).apply(list)

groupby a lambda function that extracts the first letter of each string.
then apply the grouped items to a list.
and if you want to print:
first_letter_grouped = data.groupby(data.apply(lambda x: x[0])).apply(list)
for i, strings in enumerate(first_letter_grouped):
    print(f'{first_letter_grouped.index[i]}:  {strings}')


for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda s: s[0]):
  print(k, list(g))


No, please don’t encourage newbies to code that way. Sure, _ is a valid identifier. But conventionally we use it for a discarded / ignored value. In this lambda, prefer an identifier like x, or maybe s for string.

hopefully fixed :-)
